ToC levels in Jupyter-book
I'm developing a website via Jupyter-book, in markdown, but I have a problem with the Table of Contents, which is developed with multiple files.
I understood that it can have multiple levels, i.e., chapters, sections, subsections, and subsubsections. However, I need also an additional (or, better, two additional) level, i.e., subsubsubsections.
Unfortunately, at the moment, I'm not able to visualize these levels on my menu.
I also tried with maxdepth, but:
a) I don't understand where I have to put this attribute
b) I'm afraid it can be use only to limit the depth, while I have the opposite need.
An important note: I only need to visualize the main title of each file, i.e., the one with only one #.
Could you help me? Thanks in advance.
Here, an extract of my ToC. I cannot see the L3.* levels.
format: jb-book
root: TAILOR
chapters:

file: main/Ethical_Legal_Framework/Ethical_Legal_Framework
sections:

file: main/Ethical_Legal_Framework/HLEG
file: main/Ethical_Legal_Framework/AI_ACT
sections:

file: main/Ethical_Legal_Framework/Prohibited_AI
file: main/Ethical_Legal_Framework/High_Risk_AI




file: main/Trustworthy_AI
sections:

file: Human_Agency_and_Oversight/Human_Agency_and_Oversight
title: Human Agency and Oversight
sections:

file: Human_Agency_and_Oversight/Meaningful_human_control
file: Human_Agency_and_Oversight/Causal_responsibility


file: Privacy_and_Data_Governance/Privacy_and_Data_Governance
sections:

file: Privacy_and_Data_Governance/L1.anonymization
sections:

file: Privacy_and_Data_Governance/L2.pseudonymization


file: Privacy_and_Data_Governance/L1.privacy_model
sections:

file: Privacy_and_Data_Governance/L2.differential_privacy
sections:

file: Privacy_and_Data_Governance/L3.epsilon_DP
file: Privacy_and_Data_Governance/L3.epsilon_delta_DP
file: Privacy_and_Data_Governance/L2.perturbation_mechanisms


file: Privacy_and_Data_Governance/L2.k_anonymity


file: Privacy_and_Data_Governance/L1.attacks
sections:

file: Privacy_and_Data_Governance/L2.reidentification







In addition on trying to use the maxdepth property, I also tried to bypass the problem adding a Section level, i.e., transforming the chapters in sections and the first section level in chapter, but I get lost.
